# How to download audio files

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios

I want to download audio files Asynchronously from internet through ASIHTTP request. I have written a piece of code, but it's not working properly.

```
 +(ASIHTTPRequest *)getDownloadedLectureAndSeries:(id)target :(NSString *)downloadString  FinishSelector:(SEL) finishselector FailSelector:(SEL) failselector
{
    NSString *api=downloadStrin;
    NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:api];
    [api release];

    ASIFormDataRequest *request = [ASIFormDataRequest requestWithURL:url];

    [request startAsynchronous];
    [request setDelegate:target];
    [request setDidFinishSelector:finishselector];
    [request setDidFailSelector:failselector];

    return request;
}
```

Help me, if you can. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Doesn't look like you are acctually saving the file anywhere in your code. (Unless you are trying to do it in your `finishselector`.
Add this line to have the request automatically save the file

```
[request setDownloadDestinationPath:path];
```

Where `path` is a `NSString` to where you want the file to be stored (such as your `Documents directory`

Comment: Did you get it to work? You may need to call `[request start];` as well, although I'm not sure If you are already doing so.

Comment: Thanks! i think, [request startAsynchronous]; and [request start]; are somehow same. By the way its downloading by setting path, but crashes after download.

Comment: Have you checked the selectors are being called properly? That might be the reason for the crash.

Comment: Yes! They are calling properly.

Comment: I would need more information then. What do your crash logs/debugger tell you.